# How do I increment the number in a cell of a 2D-list based on the adjacent cell's info in Python

Tags: python

The question may seem complicated, so here is my input and output.

Input:

```
[[0, X, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, X],
[0, X, 0, 0]]
```

When a cell is adjacent to 'X', it is worth 1 point. 
So this will become,

```
[[1, X, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 2, 1],
[1, 1, 2, X],
[1, X, 2, 1]]
```

Considering adjacent also covers diagonals.

What I've tried is:

```
def adx(grid, i, j):
    for move in movable:
        if not (i + move[0] < 0 or i + move[0] >= len(grid) or j + move[1] < 0 or j + move[1] >= len(grid[0])):
            if grid[i + move[0]][j + move[1]] == 'X':
                return True
    else:
        return False

for i in range(len(grid)):
    for j in range(len(grid[0])):
        if adx(grid, i, j) > 0:
            if grid[i][j] != 'X':
                grid[i][j] = 1
            else:
                grid[i][j] += 1
```

The problem with this is that it does not accumulates the score, and just puts 1 regardless.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to calculate all 'X', while you just returned while you find 1 'X'.

```
def adx(grid, i, j):
    step = 0
    for move in movable:
        if not (i + move[0] < 0 or i + move[0] >= len(grid) or j + move[1] < 0 or j + move[1] >= len(grid[0])):
            if grid[i + move[0]][j + move[1]] == 'X':
                step += 1
    return step

for i in range(len(grid)):
    for j in range(len(grid[0])):
        step = adx(grid, i, j)
        if adx(grid, i, j) > 0:
            if grid[i][j] != 'X':
                grid[i][j] = step
```

There is faster way, take a look

```
def adx(grid, i, j):
    for move in movable:
        if not (i + move[0] < 0 or i + move[0] >= len(grid) or j + move[1] < 0 or j + move[1] >= len(grid[0])):
            if grid[i + move[0]][j + move[1]] != 'X':
                grid[i + move[0]][j + move[1]] += 1

for i in range(len(grid)):
    for j in range(len(grid[0])):
        if grid[i][j] == 'X':
            adx(grid, i, j)
```